# In geometric algebra, what is the dot product of a vector and a scalar? what is the wedge product of a vector and a scalar?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, bilinear-form, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I am watching a series on geometric calculus by Alan Mcdonald and in the first episodes he states that for any vector u and multivector M: $uM = u \cdot M + u \land M$

This doesn't really take into account what happens with the 0-grade i.e scalar part of M, let's call it s.

For the identity to be true either $u \cdot s$ or $u \wedge s$ has to be zero, and from what i read previously in some instances $u \land s = us$, which implies $u \cdot s = 0$, which kind of makes intuitive sense i guess?

Comment: I suggest looking online for a written intro to geometric algebra to complement the videos. Videos can be helpful but nothing beats something in writing to learn the precise rigorous mathematical statements.

Answer (score 2):

The general dot product formula for two k-vectors $ a_r, b_s $, of grades r and s respectively, is typically defined as a grade selection of the following sort:

$$a_r \cdot b_s={\left\langle{{ a_r b_s }}\right\rangle}_{{\left\lvert {r - s} \right\rvert}}.$$

Similarly, the wedge product of the same k-vectors is defined as

$$a_r \wedge b_s={\left\langle{{ a_r b_s }}\right\rangle}_{r + s}.$$

Both of these can be extended to multivectors by decomposing that multivector into component k-vectors.

By these definitions, if $u$ is a scalar, and $v$ is a k-vector, we have

$u \cdot v = u v = u \wedge v,$

which also holds if $v$ is a multivector (and $u$ still a scalar.)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the "dot product" isn't theoretically nice. There are two definitions I've seen.

In terms of the geometric product, the first is
$$
  A_r\cdot B_s = \langle A_rB_s\rangle_{|r-s|}
$$
where $A_r$ is an $r$-vector and $B_s$ an $s$-vector, and $\langle{-}\rangle_k$ is projection onto the $k$-vector part. This definition fails the identity you cite for exactly the reason you give.

The second definition (which I will disambiguate using a fat dot) is
$$
  A_r\bullet B_s = \begin{cases}
    \langle A_rB_s\rangle_{|r-s|} &\text{if }(r\ne0\text{ and }s\ne0)\text{ or }(r = s = 0), \\
    0 &\text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$
This definition is really just tailor made to make your identity work; the explicit split on grade makes it more difficult to work with.

The theoretically best incarnation of the inner product is the *(left) contraction*
$$
  A_r\mathbin\rfloor B_s = \langle A_rB_s\rangle_{s-r}
$$
where we define the $k$-vector part for negative $k$ to be zero. This satisfies your identity:
$$
  uM = u\mathbin\rfloor M + u\wedge M.
$$
To demonstrate this products theoretical niceties, one way to define it is via the equation
$$
  \langle(A\wedge B)C\rangle_0 = \langle A(B\mathbin\rfloor C)\rangle_0
$$
for all *multivectors* $A, B, C$. In other words, it is the adjoint of the exterior product under the scalar product. It also has a simple geometric interpretation: if
$$
  [A] = \{v \in \mathbb R^n \;:\; v\wedge A = 0\}
$$
for a blade $A$ is the subspace it represents, and $B$ is another blade, then
$$
  [A\mathbin\rfloor B] = \begin{cases}
    V &\text{if }[A]\cap[B]^\perp \ne \{0\}, \\
    [A]^\perp\cap[B] & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$
The first case is equivalent to $A\mathbin\rfloor B = 0$ and we say that $[A]$ is *partially orthogonal* to $[B]$. The above characterization is true regardless of the grades of $A$ and $B$, whereas a similar statement using $\cdot$ would not be.

---

It is indeed true that
$$
  M\wedge a = a\wedge M = aM
$$
for any scalar and multivector $M$. One way to see this simply is if the wedge product is defined in terms of the geometric product
$$
  A_r\wedge B_s = \langle A_rB_s\rangle_{r+s}.
$$

Comment: My videos and books use the left contraction for the inner product. This is too much detail for the videos, which do not pretend to be a full account of geometric algebra. It is explicit in my books, which present geometric algebra in detail.

Comment: Is the first definition of the dot prlduct more or less picking the left or right contraction depending on whether r or s is bigger? To me that feels nicer than the asymetry of the L/R contractions... could you define the dot product by picking the nonzero contraction as long as you're multiplying two k-vector, and setting it to zero if you're dotting a k-vector and a scalar? Does that just become the fat dot product then?

Comment: Basically for any multivectors A and B $$A /cdot B = /Sigma_{r,s} /langle /langle A /rangle_r /langle B /rangle /rangle_|r-s|$$ for all $$r,s/neq 0$$

Comment: @Minimo I don't understand how $\cdot$ "feels nicer". Yes, it is selecting which contraction to use based on grade. But no, you cannot define it by "taking the nonzero contraction" because $A_r\mathbin\rfloor B_s$ can be zero even when $r < s$. The formula you wrote though is what I meant to write for the fat dot product, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Minimo See also the geometric interpretation I've given for $\rfloor$. This and many other properties make the contractions attractive. Note also that the dot product is maybe "more symmetric" but it is not commtative: $X\cdot Y \ne Y\cdot X$ in general. I would really like to understand how the dot product "feels nicer" since many people seem to feel this way but I just don't get it.

Comment: By "taking the nonzero contraction" i mean't excluding all grade zero object, sorry if I was a bit unclear, I was writing on mobile so formatting was a bit difficult.

Comment: Pertaining to your question why the "fat dot" seemed more naturally to me, i guess i'm simply a bit to used to the bilenear/sesquilinear forms usually designated by the "dot product"  at most varying by sign when taken in the reverse order.

Comment: @Minimo Well, it's not a bilinear form, it's a bilinear map from multivectors to multivectors, just like the geometric product and the wedge product are. It's a mixture of the ideas of orthogonalization and projection; in $A\mathbin\rfloor B$, the second blade $B$ is the space we're projecting into, and the first space $A$ is the space we're orthogonalizing. The actual bilinear form of geometric algebra is the scalar product $A*B = \langle AB\rangle_0$ (sometimes with a reversal on one multiplicand).

Comment: You know when I think about it the definition of the dot product being an L/R-contraction does kind of jive with the fact that projection really isn't a very symetric thing, you can project a line onto a plane, but projecting a plane onto a line doesn't really make sense (and so on for higher-dimensional subspaces)...